# Is there an option for yum to compile from source instead of installing pre-compiled binaries?

Tags: linux, fedora, package-management, yum, build

I've recently switched to Fedora.

I'm looking for an equivalent of the procedure described [here](http://easierbuntu.blogspot.com.es/2008/05/using-apt-get-to-compile-from-source.html) but in yum, so I can take advantage both of compiler optimization in heavily used software that [prebuild binaries can't offer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/167503/compiling-vs-using-pre-built-binaries-performance) and the virtues of having a package manager manage your installed packages.

The word "source" is not even mentioned in [the yum man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/yum).
Maybe rpm offers a way to do this?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Precompiled binaries *are* carefully optimized. In any case, given that today's CPUs are memory-bound, any minor time gained by shorter/less instructions executed will most probably be swamped by the time loading into memory, cache effects, ... Yes, everybody knows Gentoo runs twice as fast once everything is self-compiled. But that is just a "I worked *so* hard, it is just impossible I have nothing to show for it" effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download the SRPM (source RPM) packages and compile it yourself.

#### To download SRPM:

```
yumdownloader --source SOME_PACKAGE_NAME
```

If the `yumdownloader` app is not installed, install the `yum-utils` package.

#### To install necessary dependencies for compilation:

```
yum-builddep SOME_PACKAGE_NAME
```

#### To "install" SRPM package (actually unpacking the source and spec files):

```
rpm -iv somepackage-x.y.z-v.dist.src.rpm (replace with the SRPM path)
```

Now you have the source files populating your `~/rpmbuild/` directory.  You can make the necessary hacks and recompile (packages `rpm-build, rpmdevtools` and optionally `rpm-sign` are needed to rebuild from the spec file, see their man pages).  RPM packaging is rather a rich topic and the margins here are too small ... ;)

#### Fedora-specific notes

You may be interested in [`mock`](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Using_Mock_to_test_package_builds), the packaging and testing suite recommended by Fedora.